# Cape to ease sensor interface on Beaglebone

Tags: beaglebone-black

Is there a "cape" to make wiring sensors into a Beaglebone easier?

Whenever I read some guide for wiring a sensor into the Beaglebone (like [this one](http://beagleboard.org/support/BoneScript/Ultrasonic_Sensor/)) it always recommends attaching wires directly to GND, +V and signal pins, which is horribly messy and unmaintainable. Even for small projects, you end up having several wires connected to the same GND/V+ pins, so if you need to replace or repair something, you end up disrupting the wiring for every other component in your project.

Most Arduino guides assume this bad practice too, but at least I've found various ["breakout" shields](http://sandboxelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/SLD-000010.main_-399x399.jpg) to help organize GND/+V/Signal pins so I can attach individual sensor cables.

Is there anything similar for the Beaglebone? I can't find anything appropriate Googling "breakout" or "IO" cape.

Edit: The interface I'm referring to called [GVS](http://land-boards.com/blwiki/index.php?title=GVS-Pinout) and is popular in the Arduino community. Unfortunately, there's not much uptake yet in the Beaglebone community. I could only find one [GVS cape](http://beagleboard.org/project/BBB-GVS/), but looks pretty useless. Out of all the Beaglebone's pins, it only exposes 5 as true 5V GVS. All the other pins it exposes are at 3.3V or 1.8V levels, which are useless for most existing sensors.

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: @DeerHunter, Please don't tell users where they can and can't post. The question is relevant to both electronics and robotics, and userbase between them is not identical.

Comment: Why don't you create your own board, and afterwards share it with the community?